# 4 columns on a custom visual force inline page

Tags: salesforce, styling, visualforce

I have values that need to be setup like this:

[image]

Displayed like this, but with four columns:

[image]

I tried this way but this a mess...  (The above picture is an example and would have USD $ 0.00 inline with the check total): 
[image]

The code I'm using is:

```html
<apex:page standardController="BookingEvent__c" extensions="EventInclusiveTotalPriceInlineExt" standardStylesheets="true" tabstyle="BookingEvent__c" docType="html-5.0">
  <apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock mode="maindetail">
      <apex:pageBlockSection columns="4">
        <apex:outputfield value="{!be.ForecastRevenue1__c}"></apex:outputfield>
        <apex:outputfield value="{!be.ForecastRevenue2__c}"></apex:outputfield>
        <apex:outputfield value="{!be.ForecastRevenue3__c}"></apex:outputfield>
        <apex:outputfield value="{!be.ForecastRevenue4__c}"></apex:outputfield>
        <apex:outputfield value="{!be.ForecastRevenue5__c}"></apex:outputfield>
        <apex:outputfield value="{!be.ForecastRevenue6__c}"></apex:outputfield>
        <apex:outputfield value="{!be.ForecastRevenue7__c}"></apex:outputfield>
        <apex:outputfield value="{!be.ForecastRevenue8__c}"></apex:outputfield>
        <apex:outputfield value="{!be.ForecastRevenue9__c}"></apex:outputfield>
        <apex:outputfield value="{!be.ForecastRevenue10__c}"></apex:outputfield>
        <apex:outputfield value="{!be.ForecastRevenue11__c}"></apex:outputfield>
        <apex:outputfield value="{!be.ForecastRevenue12__c}"></apex:outputfield>
        <apex:outputfield value="{!be.ForecastRevenue13__c}"></apex:outputfield>
        <apex:outputfield value="{!be.ForecastRevenue14__c}"></apex:outputfield>
        <apex:outputfield value="{!be.ForecastRevenue15__c}"></apex:outputfield>
      </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

I do not know how to style and it needs to look like it is displayed in the second pic.

Any help would be great, I'm new to VF and not great at styling yet and am having troubles finding exactly what i'm looking for.

Comment: You should post this in Salesforce.Stackexchange

Comment: @Eric Thanks Eric just did!  Didn't even realize they had one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For building pretty difficult layouts on Visuaforce page you can use power of HTML and CSS, pretty often it's more convenient than Visuaforce tags.

So, for implementation of table on your first screen I would prefer to use HTML table tag in cells of which apex:outputfield tags were included.